# Passing "this" as an argument - C#

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently playing about with some XNA stuff learning to program AI. Anyway, here's my situation: Class A has a function which takes a reference to an instance of class B, does some stuff to to it, and returns it. Class B contains an instance of Class A, and then calls the function from it.

Example in code:

```
Class A
{
    B classB;

    public A()
    {
        classB = new B();
    }

    public void Act()
    {
        this = B.Do(ref this);
    }
}

Class B
{
    public A Do(ref A classA)
    {
        //Manipulate
        return classA;
    }
}
```

I've tried passing a memberwise clone .. but that didn't work, obviously, because "this" is read-only. I've no idea with this. I'm really stuck. Does anybody have any ideas? I'd ideally like to avoid having to pass every single variable in the object as a separate argument, really.

Andy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are reference types, so doing

```
Class B
{
    public void Do(A classA)
    {
        //Manipulate
    }
}
```

should manipulate the object classA references. Then in A,

```
Class A
{
    B classB;

    public A()
    {
        classB = new B();
    }

    public void Act()
    {
        B.Do(this);
    }
}
```

Note: "This does have the side effect that the reference of A that you pass cannot be set to null (it will only set the local variable to null)" - [JulianR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61632/julianr)

Comment: This does have the side effect that the reference of A that you pass cannot be set to null (it will only set the local variable to null), which might have been the original reason why it expects a ref parameter.

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't think that was the OP's intent (it wasn't), but it could have been. I'll edit to point this out.

Answer (score 1):

Your B.Do() method does it (modifying an A) double by using the ref and a return. Neither is needed to modify classA. And because you target `this` it won't work anyway. You never assign to `this`, it makes no sense.

So the Simple answer is

```
class B
{
   void Do(A anA) { anA.PublicProp = 1; }
}
```

But the circular referencing does make it a dubious design.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something specific in //Manipulate that requires you to pass a class reference as ref? And why are you also returning classA as well - that seems to be redundent if you are using ref to begin with.

Comment: The whole thing is for behaviours for simple AI (EG chase, guard, evade etc). I'm wanting to pass the entire AI entity to the behaviours so that I can keep the behaviours separate for all entities (Sort of like a single style sheet for multiple style sheets).

The reason I want to pass the whole object is that some behaviours need certain parts of the object and some don't

As for why I'm returning .. I don't quite know how I came to that decision. I'll remove it.

Comment: Single style sheet for multiple pages rather!

Answer (score 0):

just remove the ref keyword. you only need ref if you want to change the argument into something else, if you just want to manipulate it, don't use the ref.

I think it would be bad (tricky to understand) if the language allowed you to change this into that, so it disallows what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use "ref" with "this".
Why do you need the parameter to be passed by reference ?

You only need a "ref" parameter if your function must change which object the caller is refering to. If all you need is to manipulate and/or change the fields of the parameter then you do not need a ref parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For more clarity, the whole thing is for behaviours for simple AI (EG chase, guard, evade etc). I'm wanting to pass the entire AI entity to the behaviours so that I can keep the behaviours separate for all entities (Sort of like a single style sheet for multiple web pages). The reason I want to pass the whole object is that some behaviours need certain parts of the object and some don't.

As for why I'm returning .. I don't quite know how I came to that decision. I'll remove it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, Derek E!

I just tested what you said, and it worked fine.

My problem, I think, is that I was thinking that when I passed the argument it made a clone of it and manipulated that instead, like (I think ..) it does in PHP or VB (can't remember which of those I was told it does it in)

Answer (score 0):

Objects are always passed by reference and not by value. That is why we call classes in C# as reference types. Be careful if you are using structures instead since they are value types. A copy of the structure will be passed rather than the original. If you wish to pass the original then you must add the **ref** keyword. **ref** is only useful with objects if you wish to replace a reference to one object with a reference to another object.